# Pseudo classes don't work in css files,also the element tags do not work

Tags: html, css

I am using an Apache server to learn web programming. I faced this problem while writing the CSS file for my page: The pseudo-classes don't work if defined in the CSS file. Even if I define them in the HTML, they only work when I use the id tag, and not the element, it would be great if someone can provide insight as to why it is happening,i am leaving the HTML code here, as to the CSS code, I defined the pseudo classes either at the very last or very first,neither seems to work.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\styles\login.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="\images\icon\icon.ico" />
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/register.js"></script>
    <Title>Register</Title>
    <style>

            button:hover{
            background-color : #00F3FF;
        }
        button:active{
            background-color:red;
        }

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

         <div id="external">
             <div id="hide">
            <form >
            <p>Enter your email</p>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="3"><br>
            <p>Enter your username:</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="1"><br>
            <p>Enter your password:</p>
            <input type="text" name="pass"id="2"><br><br>
        
        </form>
        <button id="bt">Submit</button>
        <div id="hd">
        <p><font color=pink size=5px>Registration successful!</font></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This does not work.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console (usually F12) in your browser? Navigate to the button element and you can see that it's either overwritten by a different CSS rule (from a plugin maybe?) or that it's not applied at all (by making a typing error for example). Learning how to use the browser's console (the 'Elements' tab in Chrome) is quite essential when learning HTML/CSS.

Comment: Which pseudo elements are you talking about?

Comment: The pseudo classes defined inside the head tag

Comment: They are working here. Show your complete code.

Comment: _“Even if i define them in the html,they only work when i use the id tag,and not the element”_ - You most likely have a problem with _CSS specificity_ here - suggest you go read up on that keyword.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal thanks for the tip,indeed they were not working,i wrote the pseudo classes once more inside another file,and copied my original css into that.It seems to work now.After that i copied the whole length of the working css into my previous file,and it doesn't work anymore! Strangest thing i've seen in my entire life.

Comment: I think you're seeing the cached file, try to open your `HTML` file on Chrome then press `CTRL` simultaneously with `F5` (if you're using `Windows` as your OS)

Comment: just copied the not working code into another file and used it,works as it should

Comment: @ths i had my browser cache cleared,closed and reopened the application and restarted the computer quite a few times,did not work.Also i think browsers reload the css each time you reload the page,or am i wrong?

Comment: No, even if you restart you PC it can still use the cache. If you're on Windows try to use the key combination in my last comment.

Comment: oh alright,lemme try

Comment: @ths you're the boss,it works now,thanks!

Comment: clearing my cache from history did not work,so i was a bit baffled

Comment: @user7657046 I told you ! glad that helps.